Background option in libre calc does not work

Background option in libre calc does not work. I tried to fill the cell with red color however it did not work. I tried some online steps, I reset the user profile and used format option as well but it still didn't help. I am using 24.04 LTS ubuntu. PLEASE HELP!!
Edit: Hopefully this image will help. So I have filled the cell A-4 with yellow background color but when I move away from A-4 cell, the background color goes away

please tale the [tour] read [ask] then [edit] accordingly. There is nothing here currently that can even be attempted to answer.

Thank you for the first edit, now we're getting somewhere :) Please edit your question again and describe which exact steps you're taking to change the background color of a cell in Libre Calc. I've just did a quick test on my machine, and it works just fine.

Which version of Libreoffice are you using?

I am using 24.2 version
